# Snowflake COPY INTO from AWS S3 while including functions

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, etl, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am thinking of a few ways to do this but would like some input about effective options. The problem here is this. I need to perform some ETL actions using COPY INTO into a database I've setup for Snapshot. Which is defined as the past day. The stage here is an AWS S3 bucket. To capture the most recent files I need to implement a filepath into the from statement or pattern.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK ETL_1
WAREHOUSE = W1
SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 30 */4 * * *  America/Los_Angeles'
AS
copy into DB.SCHEMA.TABLE1
  from @STAGE/TABLE1
  pattern='.*/.*/.*[.]csv'
  on_error = 'continue'
  file_format = csv_etl;
```

Using something like this I get get the file path I need

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CURRENT_DATE_FILEPATH()
    returns string
    as 
    as REPLACE(CURRENT_DATE(), '-', '/')
    ;
```

This will return the date format like '2020/04/15' that I then want to somehow use in the stage format
 to be like @STAGE/TABLE1/2020/04/15/*

Is there a way to include this into my copy into statement?

I can do this in a procedure using Snowflake's Javascript functionality sure but unless I make a task for each procedure I will lose the granularity of being able to monitor data being loaded into every table.

As it would indeed only take one procedure looping through my tables to do this. But these tables can be fairly massive day to day.

Is this the best way?

Comment: Not the answer you want, but we effectively do what you are ask, via our own ELT (we load into SF then T in SF) tool. Thus it knows what data has been loaded, and loads days till it get to today (UTC) and then does hours.. we had to go this route prior to store procs and tasks, but really those each seem to have gaps in debug/monitoring/stats of the processes, and our orchestration app running in AWS is not a heavy load, so sit besides other apps.. so has effective zero cost..

Comment: Not a bad idea!

I did write a large procedure for this in Javascript that I will post when I have it presentable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just making this into a massive JavaScript procedure. Not ideal but I have enough error handling in it that it seems to work as I intended.